# Where can I find a kitchen faucet that stays in spray mode after turning the water off and turning it back on?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture, product-recommendation

I'm looking for a kitchen faucet with a single spray head that can toggle between spray mode and stream mode, but where the setting stays put when turning the water off and turning it back on. I asked the manufacture about [this Kraus faucet](https://www.homedepot.com/p/KRAUS-Nolen-Single-Handle-Pull-Down-Sprayer-Kitchen-Faucet-with-2-Function-Sprayhead-in-all-Brite-Spot-Free-Stainless-Steel-KPF-1673SFS/304970449)

[image: faucet in spray mode]
, but they said that it resets to stream mode after shutting the water off, as I have found most do.

Are there any particular manufacturers that make faucets that stay in spray mode after shutting the water off and turning it back on? Is there a standard industry term to search by for this functionality?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. That said, we have a Delta pull-down kitchen faucet which retains its stream/spray setting when you turn the water off and then on.

Answer (score 2):

We have a Kohler Model K-10433 that has a pushbutton near the spray head.  Pushing it one way gives a stream and pushing it the other way gives a spray.  It will remain in whatever position it was in when the water is turned off. However this unit was installed back in 2009 so I don't know what Kohler may have available now.

Answer (score 1):

Got this (https://riobelpro.ca/en/product/card/NJ201) installed in 2017.  Quebec, Canada.

Good old button, so stays how you want.